# Git reformatting entire file upon save and adding whitespace

Tags: git, github, whitespace, rider

I'm using Rider & Git, whenever I save any C# file it reformats the entire file the diff is always the entire file.

When reviewing the GitHub PR window if I click "Hide whitespace" I can see only my changes; is there a way to disable this so that it doesn't happen?

I assume it's a local Git config setting I have enabled.

Comment: It's highly likely that this is done by your IDE and not by git itself. There are hooks where you can add scripts to git that do something like that, but it's way more common that your IDE does that. It's often labeled "reformat on save" or something like that. Are you working on an existing project or have you set up your own?

Comment: Check yout Rider settings as mentioned above. It is not a git setting but an IDE one

Comment: Check the docs here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Enforcing_Code_Formatting_Rules.html

Comment: It could also be that it's changing the newline characters between windows and Unix style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's highly likely that this is done by your IDE and not by git itself. There are hooks where you can add scripts to git that do something like that, but it's way more common that your IDE does that. It's often labeled "reformat on save" or something like that. Are you working on an existing project or have you set up your own?

Yes this was a Rider setting to change the line separator.